# How to connect to the unix server which has power broker in between using java

Tags: java, unix

i need to transfer the file from local machine to unix server ,

But our unix server has a power broker (one more unix server for security)**lonindi.uk.db.com** running on port 22 .I need to login to **lonindi.uk.db.com** first and the run pbrun ssh -l (target account) (main unix server hostname)

command looks like **pbrun ssh -l fmidam gcfmi.uk.db.com** this command accepts some parameters like reason to login etc.

where **gcfmi.uk.db.com** is my main server where i should write my file .

i used jsch and able to connect to **lonindi.uk.db.com** and run command but i am stuck here not able to connect with main server .

can any1 help me please .its eating my days of time .

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: You also might want to *not* use real server names. Just don't do that. Describe the problem, and give a code example so we can understand what exactly you are doing. And give a better problem description than "I am stuck here".